# Android findViewById null only on Second Launch - Fragments - Volley HTTP

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, findviewbyid

I have an app with Fragments.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_view, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    RequestManager.getInstance(getActivity()).doRequest().Populate();
    // This is Android Volley HTTP Request Manager (using RequestProxy.java)
    // Inside Populate() I use activity.findViewById(R.id.myList), which is the list in the xml.
    // activity is MainActivity I passed to the RequestManager above.
}
```

**UPDATE: adding Populate method.**

```
public class RequestProxy {
    public Activity activity;

    public void Populate(){
        JsonArrayRequest JsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(feed_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray aJsonResponse) {

                // -----------
                // ... I work here with the response to match format, etc...
                // -----------

                // Populate list with response
                CustomAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(activity,MyArray,1);
                ListView myList = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myList);
                Log.e("myList is Null", String.valueOf(myList == null)); // Null the second time, not the first.
                if(myList!=null) myList.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            // Irrelevant...
        });
    }
}
```

}
The first time I run the app (right after installation) it works perfect.
Then, if I exit by pressing back button ( finish() ) and launch the app again, `findViewById(R.id.myList)` returns null.

Only if I use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` at `onDestroy()` method the app gets started correctly next time.

**Facts:**

- `onCreateView` is being called correctly the second time I launch the app.
- `view` is inflated correctly the second time as well.
- If I make `findViewById(R.id.myList)` inside `onActivityCreated`, it is not null. Only when I call it from Populate() it returns null.

So...

**Why does it work the fist time but not the second?**

**<s>Why is activity reference being lost the second time in Populate()?</s>**

**Update:** after some debugging, i discovered that activity reference is not lost. I can't just reference the view of the fragment.

**How can I get Popuplate() to reference the view on the Fragment from an external class.**
Something like MainActivity.fragment1.view.

**Sidenote:** I'm using more than 1 fragment (I'm just summarizing the idea here).

Comment: you have to post logs too!!

Comment: I don't want to create more confusion with logs. This is more of a conceptual problem. There's something about the lifecycle of android that makes this work wrong the 2nd time. Maybe even a bug. I need your experience to solve this mystery.

Comment: but we can't help you while you hadn't posted the logs!

Comment: I don't get errors, cause I validated the Null object case, but I am getting a null view on Populate the second time I run the app. It's very weird.

Comment: may you post rest of your code?

Comment: Just updated the Question. It's simplified of course, but it should get you a picture of my problem. I'm sure it's not a silly mistake but a bigger android lifecycle problem. If I kill the process, it works fine next time. Thanks!

Comment: you have to change activity.findViewById(R.id.myList); to (the view that you have created in your fragment).findViewById(R.id.myList);

Comment: I know. But I can't instanciate the view from within the RequestProxy class. It receives an activity in the constructor, and not a fragment.

Comment: And the big mystery is: why does it work fine at first launch and not at second? What is android doing wrong with the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is long time ago,, 
but I faced the same problem and the following article solved the problem as a charm..

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/